# Вызов onclick возвращает цикл for в php к первому элементу

Tags: php, mysql, отладка

Есть некая простая база объектов, мы их туда заносим-удаляем. Все работало корректно, пока я не добавил функцию проверки удаления (по нажатию на крестик появляется конфирм "Вы уверены?"). После этого обнаружилось, что при подтверждении форма передает в del.php id первого элемента таблицы, причем, неважно, напротив которого из них жмем крестик. В рамках отладки проверил - elemID выводится нужный, а вот в del.php попадает первый из таблицы, и удаляется, соответственно. Что не так?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Вывод объектов на странице:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM objects";
$result = mysqli_query($link,$sql) or die(mysqli_error($link));
for($data=[];$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);$data[] = $row) ;
    $result='';
    foreach($data as $elem) {
        $result.='<tr>';
        $result.='<td>'.$elem['id'].'</td>';
        $result.='<td><a href="object.php?id='.$elem['id'].'">'.$elem['obj'].'</a></td>';
        $dStart = date('d.m.Y',strtotime($elem['dStart']));
        $dFinish = date('d.m.Y',strtotime($elem['dFinish']));
        $result.='<td>'.$dStart.'</td>';
        if ($elem['finished']) {
            $result.='<td>'.$dFinish.'</td>';
            $result.='<td>'.$elem['duration'].'</td>';
        }
            else {$result.='<td> </td><td> </td>';}
        $result.='<td>'.$elem['sumObj'].'</td>';
        $result.='<td>'.$elem['sumSpend'].'</td>';
        $result.='<td>'.$elem['profit'].'</td>';
        $result.='<td>'.$elem['manager'].'</td>';
        if ($elem['finished']) {$result.='<td>Да</td>';}
            else {$result.='<td>Нет</td>';}
        $result.='<td><form action="del.php" id="delObjectAdmin" method="post"><input type="hidden" name="delObject" value="1"><input type="hidden" name="delObjectId" value="'.$elem['id'].'"><input type="button" value="X" onClick="confirmDelete(form.id);"></form></td>';
        $result.='</tr>';
    }
    echo $result;
```

Рабочая часть del.php:

```
// удаление объекта
if ((isset($_POST["delObject"]))&&($_POST["delObjectId"]) ) {
    $delObjectId = $link->real_escape_string($_POST["delObjectId"]);   
    $sql = "DELETE FROM objects WHERE id =".$delObjectId;
    if($link->query($sql)){
        echo "Данные успешно удалены";
    } else{
        echo "Ошибка: " . $link->error;
    }
}
```

Скрипт подтверждения удаления на всякий:

```
function confirmDelete(idForm) {
    if(confirm('Вы уверены?'))
        { document.getElementById(idForm).submit() }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

При отправке формы через `<button type="submit">` отправлялась текущая форма кнопки. В случае отправки формы по её идентификатору будет производиться поиск формы. По описанному выше коду видно что у всех форм будет одинаковый идентификатор, что уже делает получаемый HTML не валидным и не может гарантировать корректную работу с этими идентификаторами. Использовать уникальные идентификаторы форм или отправлять формы не по идентификатору, а относительно кликнутой кнопки.

**Первый вариант**:

```php
$result .= '<td><form action="del.php" id="delObjectAdmin' . htmlspecialchars($elem['id']) . '" method="post">'
    . '<input type="hidden" name="delObject" value="1">'
    . '<input type="hidden" name="delObjectId" value="' . htmlspecialchars($elem['id']) . '">'
    . '<input type="button" value="X" onClick="confirmDelete(' . htmlspecialchars('"delObjectAdmin' . $elem['id'] . '"') . ')">'
    . '</form></td>';
```

Не стоит так же забывать про экранирование HTML-сущностей с помощью функции [`htmlspecialchars`](https://www.php.net/htmlspecialchars).

**Второй вариант**:

```html
<input type="button" value="X" onClick="confirmDelete(this.form)">
```

```js
function confirmDelete (form) {
    if (confirm('Вы уверены?')) {
        form.submit();
    }
}
```

[Пример работы обоих вариантов на phpsandbox.io](https://phpsandbox.io/n/primer-raboty-otveta-na-vopros-stackowerflow-cww8i?files=%2Fexample2.php)

Comment: _(Если я правильно понимаю, значения id и onClick надо все-таки поменять местами)_. Попробовал оба варианта (в первом в скрипте оставил "document.getElementById(idForm).submit()", во втором - заменил на "this.form.submit()"), но: при нажатии на "Х" окно подтверждения появляется, но после подтверждения ничего не происходит - обновления страницы не происходит, строка, которой положено исчезнуть, на месте

Comment: и еще вопрос, возможно, дилетантский: почему бы не сделать в теге <form> 'id="delObjectAdmin'.elem['id'], а в кнопке 'onClick="confirmDelete(delObjectAdmin'.elem['id'].');' (без  htmlspecialchars)? Получится id вида delObjectAdmin14

Comment: @РоманЛыжов, верно, перепутал местами значения `id` и `onclick`. Внёс правки в ответ.

Comment: @РоманЛыжов, видимо я увлёкся фреймворками и забыл, что в стандартном HTML вызов через название функции не происходит. Внёс правки. Добавил ссылку на пример работы.

Comment: @РоманЛыжов, с хорошей вероятностью код будет работать и без `htmlspecialchars`. Однако я, не зная какие значения `$elem['id']` могут встречаться, перестраховываюсь на случай HTML-сущностей. Так или иначе, динамические вставки из переменных стоит экранировать в любом случае.

Answer (score 1):

Благодаря уважаемому @7-zete-7 добился работоспособности. Итоговое решение получилось таким:
вывод "крестика" для удаления:

```
$elemId=$elem['id']; // переносим значения из массива в переменную
$result.='<td><form action="del.php" id="delObjectAdmin'.$elemId.'" method="post"><input type="hidden" name="delObject" value="1"><input type="hidden" name="delObjectId" value="'.$elemId.'"><input type="button" value="X" onClick="confirmDelete(\'delObjectAdmin'.$elemId.'\');"></form></td>';
```

Остальное из вопроса - без изменений

Т.е. в id и последующем вызове функции по onclick мы "собираем" id формы из "delObjectAdmin" и соответствующего id элемента массива, делая id формы уникальным. Теперь скрипт работает корректно.
Благодарю за помощь!